# Copying a database from online source

Tags: java, android

I have one scenario for which I need help.
I included database with app in Asset folder and then used SQLiteAssetHelper, which works fine. Now the thing I want is that, I dont want to include the database with app, I want to put my database online and when the user install the app it should get the database from online source and the user should also get updates to the database from time to time. 
How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Database is in which format?? MySQL, MS Access, MS Excel, SQLite etc. Please provide the extension of db file.

Comment: You should use rest calls

Comment: I think this is not possible, however, you can connect your Android application through MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle using the web service and *GET* & *POST* calls. The best HTTP library for implment this is [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley)

Comment: have you tried this way -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application

Comment: Yes i have tried this Yogesh Rathi, But I dont want to put my database in the asset folder, i want to put it online.                                                                          Dakhs its sqlite,